# Black space showing above navigation Bar

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, ios5

1. I am not using storyboard for my iOS app.I have manually created
   UIViewController and calling from AppDelegate.The following is the
   code structure that I am using in AppDelegate.Can you please suggest
   me why app shows black space above navigation bar except in iPhone
   4S simulator.Below I have attached screenshot of my issue.[image]

   LoginView *loginView ;
   UINavigationController  *myNav ;

   loginView  = [[LoginView alloc] initWithNibName:@"LoginView" bundle:nil];

   myNav= [[UINavigationController alloc] nitWithRootViewController:loginView];

   self.window.rootViewController = myNav;
   [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add launch images for iPhone 5 & above.
Or you can include the LaunchScreen xib/storyboard.

Comment: Thank you so much. Some times unable to make my mind work better like you.